# optimize jQuery animation for better mobile performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, animation, optimization, mobile

First off, please excuse my possibly over-bloated JS function(s).. Also there are some lines of code in my script that could probably be removed. That said, Im still getting used to JS/jQuery, so any and all critique of, suggestions for, or corrections to my script are welcome.

That said, I've built up a script to animate through sections of content in a photographer's portfolio site. The script seems to run pretty well on a desktop computer, but mobile performance is clunky at best. So, Im here looking for help on how to optimize my script or add in some code to help smooth out the animations..

heres the code in action:
http://jsbin.com/icereg/2/edit

edit: updated JSbin project:
http://jsbin.com/icereg/3/edit

and here are the troublesome animation functions:

```
// Bounce Top

function bounce_top() {
    $isAnimating = 1;
    $content.animate({top: '+=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart',
        function () {
            $content.animate({top: '-=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $isAnimating = 0;
        });
} // end bounce_top()



// Bounce Right

function bounce_right() {
    $isAnimating = 1;
    $content.animate({left: '-=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart',
        function () {
            $content.animate({left: '+=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $isAnimating = 0;
        });
} // end bounce_right()



// Bounce Bottom

function bounce_btm() {
    $isAnimating = 1;
    $content.animate({top: '-=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart',
        function () {
            $content.animate({top: '+=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $isAnimating = 0;
        });
} // end bounce_btm()



// Bounce Left

function bounce_left() {
    $isAnimating = 1;
    $content.animate({left: '+=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart',
        function () {
            $content.animate({left: '-=44'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $isAnimating = 0;
        });
} // end bounce_left()



    // Scroll Content

function scroll_content() {

    $isAnimating = 1;

    if ($curr_section === ($total_section - 1) && ($event_target === 'down' || ($event_target === 'scroll' && $mouse_delta < 0))) {
        // we're at the bottom;  - 1 because of included 0 section; 
        bounce_btm();

    } else if ($curr_section === 0 && ($event_target === 'up' || ($event_target === 'scroll' && $mouse_delta >= 0))) {
        // we're already at the top
        bounce_top();

    } else if ($event_target === 'down' || $event_target === 'up' || $event_target === 'scroll' || $event_target === 'nav') {
        // now either UP or DOWN inputs (mouse wheel, keyboad, nav links)

        $nav_work_links.removeClass('active_nav');
        $('#right_arrow').add('#left_arrow').remove();

        if ($event_target === 'down' || ($event_target === 'scroll' && $mouse_delta < 0)) { // down or scroll down
            $curr_section = $curr_section + 1;
            $vertslidePos = '-=675';

        } else if ($event_target === 'up' || ($event_target === 'scroll' && $mouse_delta >= 0)) { // up or scroll up
            $curr_section = $curr_section - 1;
            $vertslidePos = '+=675';

        } else if ($event_target === 'nav') {
            // now nav click inputs
            $curr_section = $event_target_eq;
            $vertslidePos = '-' + ($curr_section * 675);
        }
        if ($curr_page > 1) {
            $content.animate({marginLeft: 0}, 450, 'easeInOutQuart'); // end .animate() method
        }
        $content.animate({top: $vertslidePos}, 450, 'easeInOutQuart',
            function () {
                if ($('.nav_work_items').eq($curr_section).index() === 0) {
                    $nav_work_links.removeClass('active_nav');
                } else {
                    $('.nav_work_items').eq($curr_section - 1).find('.nav_work_links').addClass('active_nav');
                }
                $('.active_nav').before($left_arrow).after($right_arrow);
                $curr_page = 1;
                window.location.hash = '#work' + $curr_section;
                $isAnimating = 0;
            }); // end .animate() method    

    } else if ($event_target === 'left' || $event_target === 'right') {
        // now either RIGHT or LEFT inputs
        $right_arrow = $('#right_arrow');
        $left_arrow = $('#left_arrow');
        $active_nav = $('.active_nav');
        $total_pages = $('#work' + $curr_section).children('.workcontent').length;

        if ($curr_page === $total_pages && $event_target === 'right') {
            bounce_right();

        } else if ($curr_page === 1 && $event_target === 'left') {
            bounce_left();

        } else {

            if ($event_target === 'right') {
                $curr_page = $curr_page + 1;
                $horzslidePos = '-=600px';

            } else if ($event_target === 'left') {
                $curr_page = $curr_page - 1;
                $horzslidePos = '+=600px';
            }

            $content.animate({marginLeft: $horzslidePos}, 450, 'easeInOutQuart',
                function () {
                    $isAnimating = 0;
                }); // end .animate() method
        }
    }

} // end scroll_content();
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, and it's not even in your question. Can you post the relevant parts of it (e.g. the animations that suffer the worst performance penalties on mobile devices) in your question itself?

Comment: Yea i tried to keep all the content movement to one big function that accounts for all possible navigation inputs (keypresses, element clicks, mousewheel scrolling) .. would it have been better to split up the animation into smaller, more specific individual functions instead?

Comment: At first glance, most probably yes, if only from a readability/maintainability standpoint. `scroll_content()` contains a lot of branches that depend on `$curr_section` or `$event_target` and could benefit from being abstracted into their own functions/handlers. That's hard to say without seeing its call sites, but from your jsbin link I'd say it's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: OK, so I took your advice and broke this beast down into 4 separate functions based on direction of movement. It does indeed improve performance on mobile, but only just noticeably so. Im definitely happier with my updated code, but is there anything else I can do to further smooth out the animation on mobile?

Comment: Also, should I update the code sample above to reflect the changes I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was and still am a JS n00b, and my code then was way over-bloated. Some simple consolidation and reformulation really did help. However, there's also this JS plugin these days to help smooth JS animations:

[Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)

.....and for those that might land here in the future, here's something even better:

[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)